# Replacing string within a file using bash + environmental variables

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix, sed

Let's say for simplicities sake I have a file (please forgive my useless pseudo code)

file.txt

```
std::string filename = "filename.txt"

double v_no = 2.0;

const int v_minor = 0; // < --- Target

std::string random_var1 = "Hello"
std::string random_var2 = "Hello 2"

int main()
{
    // .. 
}
```

And I have a bash file in the same directory - set_version.sh

I want to replace a string in this file with this script - specifically "v_minor = 0" with "v_minor = $VARIABLE" - in my case the variable will be an environmental set on a server.

So lets say it has been successfully run a couple of times. Now the string reads "v_minor = 2". I still want the same set_version.sh script to change 2 to whatever the variable is.

In the windows build of my software I have a batch file that changes "v_minor = %d" to "v_minor = %VERSION%".

My question is how I do something similar in bash? E.g. ignoring what the decimal is in the string and changing it to variable.

What I've got so far:

set_version.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=75

sed -i '' 's/v_minor = %d/v_minor = $VERSION/g/' file.txt
```

Version var being set is just for testing purposes.

This returns error

```
sed: 1: "s/v_minor = %d/v_minor  ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

I'm running Mac OS X Yosemite for this test.

Again, essentially %d can be any integer.

Thank you

Comment: just to confirm, `%d` will not match "any integer",  you need to use `[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will work for you:

```
sed -i '' "s/v_minor = .*$/v_minor = $VERSION/g" file.txt
```

.*$ means till the end of that string.
Don't forget to use  `" "` when operating with variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '' 's/v_minor = %d/v_minor = $VERSION/g/' file.txt
#                                             ^
#                                            /
#                       remove this slash ---
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I would suggest another easier way as follows (and simplicity will make less bugs...):

First, Change your target to

```
const int v_minor = V_MINOR; // < --- Target
```

Second, add an include line, anywhere before the target statement:

```
#include "version.h"
```

Third, write a script to generate the version.h similar to the followings:

```
#ifndef _VERSION_H_
#define V_MINOR  0           // <== this 0 is what you want to change.
#endif
```

Generate a script to output the said version.h is too simple (Just some fixed prints plus the target number). Thus, I don't provide it here.

Comparing to those possible error-prone sed-awk-perl solution, I prefer this simple solution.

Comment: Extreamly speaking, the version line may look like this: `const int v_minor = /* version */ 0;`  A simple sed/awk can not easily retain those comments and replace the `0`, not to say that `0` can be placed in the next line, i.e. "First line: `v_minor =`, and "Second line: `0;`.  That will require a parser understanding C Language syntax.  Even the spaces around the equal sign ('=') can make problems, not to say some usage like `if (v_minor == 5)` can be wrongly parsed by sed/awk, replacing the second `=` to the target number causing compile time error.

Comment: This seems like a much more efficient/less hacky way of doing it. And something I can easily do on Windows version too. Thank you.

Comment: Further, rather than always changing the ".h" file, the version could be passed at build time, eg, "make ... -D{var}={value}..."; this is more commonly done for build numbers, but you could also get your version number from the environment this way, eg from a txt file or from git, etc.

Comment: Atlassian Bamboo is what is handling my builds + dev releases. Essentially what I am doing is setting an environmental variable in Bamboo "VERSION=${bamboo.buildNumber}". And then referencing that in my software by parsing VERSION into the header file. A script that sets the variable in version.h to bamboo.buildNumber is executed at Bamboo build time - just before my make + packaging is executed.